# how to create a pickle file correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, contextmanager

I am trying to create a pickle file.
I have used the following piece of code to do it:

```
def pickler(input_nparray):
    with open('/Users/username/Desktop/pklfilename.pkl', 'wb+') as f:
        pickle.dump(input_nparray, f)
```

This method works perfectly. What this does is it takes in the numpy array and stores the contents into the pklfilename.pkl.

But the problem here is I have to specify the filename. This I tried to do in the following way, but failed.

```
def pickler(input_nparray, pklfilename):
    with open('/Users/swaghccc/Desktop/' + pklfilename, 'wb+') as f:
        pickle.dump(input_nparray, f)

pickler(input_nparray, 'file1.pkl')
```

Can someone tell me the correct alternative?

Comment: how does it fail?

Comment: It does not create a pickle file. There is no error in the code.

Comment: What is the value of `pklfilename` in your second code snippet?

Comment: So with code snippet one, a file called pklfilename.pkl is being generated. But in code snippet , file called file1.pkl is not being generated.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren It is file1.pkl

Answer (score 0):

The username differs between the first and second example. Change it to `username` and use the filename `pklfilename.pkl` and see if you end up with a file in the second example.

Another tip is to save the filename in a variable a print it to try to figure out what goes on.